# Are there any performance improvements when using static vertices in Titan?

Tags: graph-databases, titan, vertices, nosql

I just read about [static vertices in Titan 0.5.0](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.0/advanced-schema.html) and I was wondering whether you could get any performance improvements when defining them as such?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static vertices in Titan primarily serve two purposes:

1. To guard against accidental deletion or modification
2. To allow TTL of vertices

There aren't any performance improvements for static vertices *yet*. As we improve Titan's caches, you will see that static vertices can be cached much fore effectively.